# haproxy not restricting to TLS 1.2

Tags: tls1.2, haproxy

Having troubles understanding where I am messing up, I want to disable TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 so SSL Labs improves my cert score.

I have tried adding the force tls1_2 line in HAproxy as well to no avail. I am still learning more about TLS but from what I understand this should work.

Configuration:

```
Cloudflare -> Haproxy -> backend server
Cloudflare origin cert is between cloudflare and haproxy
```

Haproxy Config (in regards to TLS)

````
global
 ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 prefer-client-ciphers
 ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!aNULL:!SHA1:!AESCCM
 ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
 ssl-default-server-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2
 ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!aNULL:!SHA1:!AESCCM
 ssl-default-server-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256```


frontend https-in
 bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/domainhere.com.pem ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 force-tlsv12
````

Openssl.conf

```
#system Default
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sec]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_defualt_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

Versions:

HAProxy version 2.4.4-1ppa1

OpenSSL 1.1.1f

Answer (score 1):

The ha proxy config seems correct.

Did you try openssl command on your ha proxy? By varying the tls version?

Something like

```
openssl s_client -connect <YourHost>:443 -servername <YourHost> -tls1_0
openssl s_client -connect <YourHost>:443 -servername <YourHost> -tls1_1
openssl s_client -connect <YourHost>:443 -servername <YourHost> -tls1_2
```

Notice that you had to supply the hostname twice. The -connect switch is used to establish the TCP connection, but -servername is used to specify the hostname sent at the TLS level. Starting with OpenSSL 1.1.1, the s_client tool automatically configures the latter.
You’ll still need to use the -servername switch if

1. you’re using an earlier version of OpenSSL,
2. you’re connecting to an IP address
3. the TLS host needs to be different.

Comment: Yea, doing that returns cert info for all the protocols.

Comment: Well, it means that you can use TLS v1.0 1.1 and 1.2
How did you compile HA-Proxy ?
Moreover  "force-tlsv12" or "ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2" is useless in  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/domainhere.com.pem ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2 force-tlsv12.
Either specify the minimum version or force the TLS version but the two together is useless
I don't know if that can cause problems.

Comment: I discovered the issue, Cloudflare was acting as the primary endpoint and there was a setting that was more difficult to find that would allow "less secure" TLS configurations. 

once this was turned off, everything worked like it should.

Comment: Okay.
Otherwise, this link could be usefull for generating different TLS config.
https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy&version=2.4&config=intermediate&openssl=1.1.1f&guideline=5.6

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who stumbles upon this after fighting with HAProxy...

Cloudflare -> SSL/TLS -> Edge Certificates -> Minimum TLS Version

Cloudflare still defaults to TLSv1.0 so you will need to change this to get a better SSL Server Test score.

Comment: after 30 minutes of head scratching... bless u Steven.